# Regex "easy" one -> post deleted afterwards

Tags: regex

**Input**:

`Hello fr. 2 699:- 2 fr. 599:- 3 fr. 899:- 4 fr. 3 899:- 5 fr. 1 499:- 6 fr. 999:-.`

**Output**:

```
599 899 999
```

Where do I put in "Hello " in:

```
/(?<=fr\.\s)(\d{3})/
```

I test at : http://rubular.com/

Comment: Your question lacks explanation of what you're truly trying to accomplish. What are you trying to do with "Hello" if it looks like you only want to match the numbers?

Comment: I dont want "Hello" to match (output) but it has to part of the input (see input serie)

Comment: yes its a duplicate but I dont get it solved...

Comment: Downvote because the question is practically illegible - why is the output 599 899 999? Where did 499 go?

Comment: Read question! "499" is part of a thousand number (1 499) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you require 'Hello' in the regular expression, then you can apply the positive lookbehind to both 'Hello' and 'fr.'

```
(?<=(Hello)|(fr\.\s))\d{3}
```

Comment: Thanks but this matches "699", "599", "899", "899", "499", "999"

Comment: You lacked specification of the 'desired' output and only mentioned an output, which I took as the output you were receiving but not wanting. Clarification on desired output is useful when creating your questions.

Comment: Point taken. Maybe I should have written "Output only". Still, I cannot find out where to put "Hello " in the regex. "Hello " is a pre-req for the output.

Comment: You want Hello as an output or not, or that it's required to be in your regular expression?

Comment: not output, yes just required to be in regular expression

Comment: BRILLIANT! Now its working (the original posting from Signus) @Signus. THANKS A LOT! You solved it!!!!!!! Unfortunately I need 15 positives votes but I got so many negative now so I cant give you credits...

Comment: Well you should be able to accept an answer if you can't upvote. The reason people downvoted your question because there's no explanation and practically no description of your problem.

Comment: I will. Last question. If there are other texts and numbers before "Hello" can the regex start from the "Hello" and avoid/disregards everything before "Hello". Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Yes this has a positive lookbehind, meaning 'Hello' and 'fr.' are matched but excluded, and everything else is discarded. If this is a homework question, you may want to start with an intro to Regular Expressions.